# Can't connect activities in activity diagram in EA

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

Hi I'm currently stuck with a problem with Activity diagram in EA. I'm trying to describe a code. When I add Start controll node and activity node I'm not able to connect them by control flow.

The same problem happens when I try to connect two activities together with control flow - I'm getting following error:

> The requested connection is not UML compliant

Anybody can give some advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: Which EA version?

Comment: Please consider choosing Geert's answer (first to see the basic issue) as the correct one and upvote Bruno's answer as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: Please look down the other answers here. I just did not read correctly about what you were doing. This one is meant for the cases where EA did block users the wrong way. In your case it's blocking you for good reasons

### Original answer

You can turn off "Strict connector syntax" in the Connector options. You find that in various places in EA's option jungle depending on the version. V14 has a couple of known bugs related to that. Not sure about V15 or any state of fixing that.

---

In V13.5 you find that option under Layout/Appearance/Theme & ...

[image]

(right bottom)

Answer (score 5):

Enterprise Architect is right. Control flows are not allowed from or to Activities in the UML metamodel. *(I'm actually glad they finally start following the UML metamodel more)*

What you are doing wrong (and you are not alone) is that you are putting Activities on an Activity Diagram.

An Activity is supposed to be the *owner* of your Activity Diagram. On the diagram itself you only use **Actions**

You can compare this to State Machines and State Machine Diagrams. The State Machine is the owner of the diagram an on the diagram itself you only use **States**, not State Machines.

An Activity is more like a State Machine, where an Action is more like a State.

See also the article I wrote about this subject: [UML Best Practice: There are no Activities on an Activity Diagram](https://bellekens.com/2012/12/09/uml-best-practice-there-are-no-activities-on-an-activity-diagram/)

Comment: OH, you're damn right. I didn't read carefully. I was about to add something like "you break sanity checks that way" but then forgot about it. +1

Answer (score 2):

> When I add Start controll node and activity node I'm not able to connect them by control flow.
>
> The same problem happens when I try to connect two activities together with control flow

E.A. is right to refuse these flows, they have no sense

Rather than to add activities in your diagram use *call behavior actions* whose behavior is an activity, in that case a fork is drawn in the action to indicate that case. Example with [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) :

[image]

The behavior of a *call behavior action* can also be a state machine.

Comment: Yes, using a call behavior is what should be done. See my comment at Geert's answer. This one also +1

Comment: @qwerty_so yes, tools are not always bad blocking us :-))